# Software alternative to EasyWorship

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a software alternative to [EasyWorship](https://www.easyworship.com/).
This is a church software to manage slides showing either Bible verses or song lyrics or just plain text for projection.

Among the core features I'm looking for are:

- Support for multiple Bible translations and searchable.
- A searchable database of song lyrics that we can add more too.
- Have a 'live' area in the main interface where live content that is being shown on the projector is shown.
- Use of custom images or colors as background.
- Can really help if I can shadow or outline text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are few recommendations

- [OpenLP](http://openlp.org/en/features) (I think it is the best)
- [EpicWorship](http://www.quvizo.com/central/epicworship)
- [Quelea](http://quelea.org/)
- [OpenSong](http://www.opensong.org/)

Comment: I'll give each a try and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Openlp does everything you ask and more and is in fact pretty much identical in use to Easy Worship (i.e., if you're used to EW it'll take you 10 minutes to get used to openlp). It's also available in the general package repository, at least for Linux Mint.